# How can I have two bar charts side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, sidebyside

I am new on LaTeX and Overleaf, and trying to place bar charts side by side with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny
\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[!h]

\begin{centering}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(a)},
    symbolic y coords={F, E, D, C, B, A },
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
    \addplot coordinates {(35,A) (24,B) (23,C) (21,D) (19,E) (17,F)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(b)},
    symbolic y coords={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
    \addplot coordinates {(63,A6) (53,A5) (16,A4) (14,A3) (9,A2) (8,A1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{An overview on of side by side bar charts}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the `xlabel`s  suposed to be subfigure numbers? If so, I would recommens using either the `subfig` or `subcaption` package in order to get automatic subfigure numbering. Why not place the two bar charts into two separate `tikzpicture` environments?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! but charts are still  not side by side , its in top and down position now.

Comment: Is there an empty line between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}`?  If so, remove it. Also, did you decide to incorporate the `subfig` or `subcaption` package?

Comment: Thanks alot, problem is solved, I used with and without subfig or subcaption packages. and its work now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Unfortunately your question as well answer are not entirely clear and erroneous (misses are packages, closing braces, ...). Consequently the most of code in my MWE is written from scratch. See, if can help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{subcaption}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm,
    xbar,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    enlarge x limits={0.3,upper},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
            }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel={(a)},
symbolic y coords={A, B, C, D, E, F},
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(35,A) (24,B) (23,C) (21,D) (19,E) (17,F)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[    
xlabel={(b)},
symbolic y coords={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6},
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(63,A6) (53,A5) (16,A4) (14,A3) (9,A2) (8,A1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{An overview on of side by side bar charts}
\label{fig}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\pgfplotsset{
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm,
    xbar,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    enlarge x limits={0.3,upper},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        xbar,
    enlarge y limits=0.1,
    enlarge x limits={0.3,upper},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
            }
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel={(a)},
symbolic y coords={F, E, D, C, B, A },
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(35,A) (24,B) (23,C) (21,D) (19,E) (17,F)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{SubCaption1}
    \label{fig:subim1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.28\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5.6cm]{mesh}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
    \caption{SubCaption2}
    \label{fig:subim2}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel={(b)},
symbolic y coords={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6},
                ]
\addplot coordinates {(63,A6) (53,A5) (16,A4) (14,A3) (9,A2) (8,A1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{SubCaption3}
    \label{fig:subim3}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
    \label{fig:image2}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny
\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[!h]

\begin{centering}
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(a)},
    symbolic y coords={F, E, D, C, B, A },
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
    \addplot coordinates {(35,A) (24,B) (23,C) (21,D) (19,E) (17,F)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(b)},
    symbolic y coords={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
    \addplot coordinates {(63,A6) (53,A5) (16,A4) (14,A3) (9,A2) (8,A1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\caption{An overview on of side by side bar charts}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(a)},
    symbolic y coords={F, E, D, C, B, A },
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot coordinates {(35,A) (24,B) (23,C) (21,D) (19,E) (17,F)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
%\caption{Caption1}
%\label{fig:subim1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth, height=5cm]{mesh}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %tiny,
    xbar, 
    width=5.6cm, height=7.0cm, 
    enlarge y limits=0.01,
    enlargelimits=0.07,  
    xlabel={(b)},
    symbolic y coords={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6},
    ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    %every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
    \addplot coordinates {(63,A6) (53,A5) (16,A4) (14,A3) (9,A2) (8,A1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
%\caption{Caption 2}
%\label{fig:subim2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code does not compile without errors.

Comment: And could you please write something to explain what you changed and why? This actually improves the answer beyond a wall of code.